# How to build a visual studio 2010 solution into a standalone dll?

Tags: c#, c++, c, visual-studio-2010, dll

I have a visual studio 2010 project, uses static and dynamic libs (`.lib` and `.dll`), the project is compiled and built successfully as `.exe` both in release and debug modes, the code is c and c++.

What is the right way to compile and wrapping all the solution to one standalone `.dll` file.

I want to have one dll file, I'll be able to load it in other c, c++, c# project safely.

in my case I want to load it in [teraterm](http://ttssh2.sourceforge.jp/manual/en/reference/develop.txt) and in other simple self developed c# application.

Comment: A solution cannot compile to a single dll per-se. Each project in a solution is built to a specific build target, whether that be a dll, exe, or something else. To have only one dll, you should only have one project in your solution. What you probably want is to have one project that compiles to a dll (so it can be loaded in a different application) and a different project that references the other and compiles to an exe.

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2016722/one-dll-multiple-projects

Comment: I can't decide whether this question is superficial or incredibly deep.  Perhaps there's something I'm missing because I'm not familiar with teraterm or indeed the reasoning behind wrapping an executable into a DLL - executables and DLLs serve different purposes.  That said, are you in full control of all DLLs involved in the project?  Are the DLLs linked explicitly (through lib files) or are they invoked with `LoadLibrary`?  To make a single DLL you would need to convert these to use static linkage.

Comment: This might be a detail, however unexpected details could break one or the other approach, so: "*... most of the code is c and c++.*" and the rest is made of what?

Comment: @alk all the code is in c or c++. thanks

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio has a C++ linker option called "Link Library Dependencies": http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/024awkd1(v=vs.90).aspx

This would link the object files from all projects in the solution directly into the project output (via dependency tracking). Be careful when you use this though, if you use this in an EXE and the DLLs you're linking export symbols your EXE will also export them.

**Update:**

Here's more detail: What happens is that instead of linking the DLLs (this assumes you have the DLLs you'd like to link set as dependencies of your project in the solution) to produce separate binaries, the linker takes the outputs from each individual project dependency and links them into the final executable/DLL directly, thus creating a monolithic DLL.

A side effect is that (depending on the code) the overall size of the output is reduced a little, the monolithic DLL (or EXE) might be large in general, but smaller in size than the individual output files combined due to link-time optimisations. Any symbols exported by the  objects linked will be exported by the final DLL, since they are marked as such in the compilation step.

Comment: Sounds like a good solution, I tried it several times on linux using GCC, it makes your program huge, but it works. Do I miss something? if you can enrich your answer and other confirm it is the solution I'll mark it up. +1 thanks.

Comment: Done, sorry if it seemed a little vague before, hadn't slept much and wanted to reply quickly before bed.
**Edit:** I wouldn't recommend doing this on Linux though, it can certainly mess with the dependencies and unless you rebuild your binary on every platform it might be hard to redistribute it to users without causing potential problems. It all depends on what kind of libraries you link and whether or not they have platform-specific code though.

Answer (score 0):

There's may be a catch, but being in VS2010, you should just click on the startup project, select 'properties' ->
'configuration properties' -> 'general' -> 'configuration type' -> set it to 'dynamic library (dll)'

Comment: can you please enrich your answer?